# Problems with MSGraph POST in SPFx React

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, react, microsoft-graph, ms-graph-client

I am fairly new to MSGraph and I have a problem with the POST request.
I am currently building an app in SharePoint Framework with React which should send a message to the typed email with subject and message.

Here I send my file structure:

[image: File structure]

Here is the SendmailWebPart.ts file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseClientSideWebPart,
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

import * as strings from 'SendmailWebPartStrings';
import Sendmail from './components/Sendmail';
import { ISendmailProps } from './components/ISendmailProps';

import { MSGraphClientFactory, MSGraphClient } from '@microsoft/sp-http';

export interface ISendmailWebPartProps {
  description: string;
}

export default class SendmailWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<ISendmailWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<ISendmailProps > = React.createElement(
      Sendmail,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        spfxContext: this.context
      }
    );

    this.context.msGraphClientFactory
        .getClient()
        .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
            client
              .api('/me')
              .get((error, response: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
                console.log("Any Graph Response? " + JSON.stringify(response));

              })
        });


    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Sendmail.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './Sendmail.module.scss';
import { ISendmailProps } from './ISendmailProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import { EmailForm } from './EmailForm'

export default class Sendmail extends React.Component<ISendmailProps, {}> {
  public render(): React.ReactElement<ISendmailProps> {
    return (
      <div className={ styles.sendmail }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <div className={ styles.column }>
              <span className={ styles.title }>Welcome to SharePoint messenger!</span>
              <EmailForm description={this.props.description} spfxContext={this.context}></EmailForm>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

ISendmailProps.ts:

```
import { WebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";

export interface ISendmailProps {
  description: string;
  spfxContext: WebPartContext;
}

export interface ISendmailState {
  emailTo: string;
  subject: string;
  message: string;
}
```

And finally here is the component EmailForm.tsx in which I have the issue:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './Sendmail.module.scss';
import { ISendmailProps, ISendmailState } from './ISendmailProps';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import { TextField, PrimaryButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
import { MSGraphClientFactory, MSGraphClient } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import { ServiceKey } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';


export class EmailForm extends React.Component<ISendmailProps, ISendmailState>{
    /**
     *
     */
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            emailTo: 'dddddddddd.cx',
            subject: 'dsdsd',
            message: 'dsdsdsdsdcdcdcdcdcdcdc'
        }
    }



    //Render Email. Show the attributes
        public render(): React.ReactElement<ISendmailState> {
            return(
                <div>
                    <TextField label="Email to " value={this.state.emailTo} onChange={this._handleMailTo.bind(this)}    required />
                    <TextField label="Subject  " value={this.state.subject} onChange={this._handleSubject.bind(this)}   required />
                    <TextField label="Message  " value={this.state.message} onChange={this._handleMessage.bind(this)}   multiline rows={3} />
                    <PrimaryButton text="Send Message" onClick={() => {this._sendEmail(event)} } /> 
                </div>
            )
        }

        //Method
        private _handleMailTo(e) {
            this.setState({
                emailTo: e.target.value,
            });
        }
        private _handleSubject(e) {
            this.setState({
                subject: e.target.value
            });
        }
        private _handleMessage(e) {
            this.setState({
                message: e.target.value
            });
        }

        //Send Email
        private async _sendEmail(e): Promise<void> {
            alert("Email Sent!");
            console.log(this.state.emailTo);
            console.log(this.state.subject);
            console.log(this.state.message);

            const graphClient : MSGraphClient = this.context.serviceScope.consume(MSGraphClient.serviceKey)

            const options = {
                authProvider,
            };

            const myClient = Client.init(options);

            const sendMail = {
                message: {
                    subject: this.state.subject,
                    body: {
                        contentType: "Text",
                        content: this.state.message
                    },
                    toRecipients: [
                        {
                          emailAddress: {
                            address: this.state.emailTo
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                }
            };

            let res = await myClient.api('/me/sendMail')
                                    .post(sendMail);

        }
}
```

The problem is, I don't understand why when I type :

```
this.context.serviceScope.consume(MSGraphClient.serviceKey)
```

servicekey doesn't exist because I have seen someone else doing it without errors.

And the second problem is with authProvider and Client even though I am following this documentation:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript

Here I will provide a screenshot of the errors:

[image: Errors]

Here are my approved Graph API:s in API-management:
[image]

I would appreciate if someone please could help me out here.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If there is no particular reason using Microsoft graph then you can use an easy option using PnP JS: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-SP.Utilities.Utility **OR** check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ihke7fUkBp0) video if it is helpful.

Comment: @GaneshSanap it is that video I have been watching many times before even asking this question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample demo to send email. `this.props.context` the context is from webpart(.ts).

```
const sendMail = {
      message: {
        subject: "Test",
        body: {
          contentType: "Text",
          content: "test email in SPFx call."
        },
        toRecipients: [
          {
            emailAddress: {
              address: "lee@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
          }
        ],
        ccRecipients: [
          {
            emailAddress: {
              address: "lee@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      saveToSentItems: "false"
    };

    this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory
      .getClient()
      .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
        // get information about the current user from the Microsoft Graph
        client
          // .api('/me')
          // .get((error, response: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
          //   let user = response.displayName;
          // });
          .api('/me/sendMail')
      .post(sendMail).then(()=>{
        console.log('email send');
      })
      });
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer all your question, but this is to the first error `MSGraphClient.serviceKey`,

Since 1.6 the MSGraphClient and AadHttpClient classes no longer expose a serviceKey property which means that we cannot get hold of the default instances in custom services without passing in the entire web part context.

We get this error:

> Property 'serviceKey' does not exist on type 'typeof MSGraphClient'